# Retrieve Shared Data Extension records using WSProxy

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to retireve records from a shared Data Extension using WS Proxy and I always get **DataExtension doesn't exist** error. I'm using the below sample code.

```
<script runat="server">
  
Platform.Load('core', '1');
    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var deName = 'ENT.Test Data Extension';
    var cols = [
                "col1",
                "col2",
                "col3",
                "col4"
            ];

    var desc = api.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deName + "]", cols, filter, true);
  
    Write(Stringify(desc));

</script>
```

I'm running the above script in the child BU. I think this might be an issue with the name Format I'm using for Shared Data Extension.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either. I wonder if you need to pass the client and user id, but I didn't have much luck there either.